# Bundling nodes in d3js

Tags: javascript, java, d3.js, error-handling, encoding

I am trying to bundle nodes using the below javascript any help would be appreciated and the original code can found below:
https://codepen.io/suchibharani/pen/xxbgrKd

```
function bundleNodes(groupId) {
    var bundleFactor = 0.1; // Adjust this value to control the bundling intensity
    node
        .filter(function(d) { return d.group == groupId; })
        .each(function(d) {
            var dx = centroid[0] - d.x;
            var dy = centroid[1] - d.y;
            d.x += dx * bundleFactor;
            d.y += dy * bundleFactor;
            // Optionally, you can fix the nodes' positions after bundling to prevent them from moving back due to the force simulation.
            // d.fx = d.x;
            // d.fy = d.y;
        });
    simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart(); // Reheat the simulation to reflect changes
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.